# How do I push mongodb data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications

So I have developed a web app as a hobby on Handlebars, Express and Mongoose/MongoDB.

The app let's users create an account and then post advertisements for other users to see and respond to.

All the ads posted by users show up on the index page. So it is common view for all the users on this web app. I am relatively new to web development so to build such a simple app it took me a while but boy I learned a lot!

Now the issue I am facing is, when a user A posts an Ad while the user B is logged in and is currently on the index page (a page that lists all the ads posted) it won't show up for user B unless user B refreshes the page. Rightly so actually because only when the index page's route is hit it will query all the ads and refreshing is basically hitting the index route I get that. But I don't want it that way. I want it to show the new ad on user B's index and pretty much every user's index if there's new ad by any user.

So I did a little research/reading and I learned that I can do it by learning to work with triggers on mongodb and like create some kind of trigger that when a new ad is posted do something. I like the idea but failed to find resources to learn how to use such a thing.

The other option I was suggested was to use socket.io but that too I can't grasp how can I make an entire Ad document work as a socket. I am lost and implementing this feature of dynamically loading ads for all users will complete this hobby project of mine and will help me find a junior dev job in local community.

I request stackoverflow's community to guide me how do I go about doing this and what resources I can use to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

The socket.io seems to be the best solution for your case. What you will want to do with socket.io is every time a user posts an Ad you use socket.io to notify the rest of the users that there is an update.

If you don't want to send the entire document using the socket you can use the socket to notify the clients and on the client side every time you receive such a notice from the server you will either

a) Refresh the page(not suggested as it will make the user experience unpleasant) which is easier to implement

OR

b) You can use an Ajax request to get the new data from your server and update the fields on the fly(which makes for a better user experience).

Answer (score 0):

Best Way You can come with using **Short Polling** concept from client side to ask for new data after 1 or 2 seconds (whatsoever count to need ) . **Gmail** for new inbox mails also uses `sync` method in a particular fashion . Just ask from server for new data

**OR** Second option to go through below

**On Server Side**

Serve `index.html` page  to User A (which is logged in now).
Some User B inserts data 
 
Maintain a function or a cron job (checks the count of Total Ads ) Lets say after every 1 minute or so 
If there is change in count from the previous total_count , update it and  get new mlab documents and send it to function , Let's say **push_new_ads** which will be sync via socket.io to client

**On Client Side**

Sync your `client_total_count` with `server_local_count` **push_new_ads** using socket.io and If there is change in count , make a simple `fetch api` call to get data and appends it to previously fetched array

There is no such way to directly listen the changes in mongodb But you can trigger some changes from oplog using tailable cursors